# How to correctly name a multi-select element in forms?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

How to correctly name this in English (in an official documentation for an IT system or in an instruction for filling up some form):

[image]

Should I name this:

- a checkbox,
- a check box,
- a tickbox,
- a tick box,
- *other name*.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkbox), all four options are good.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty nice answer instead of just comment. Care to rewrite as full-featured answer?

Comment: See my answer to your other question: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/368075/194459

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkbox), all four options are good. But *checkbox* (as one or two words) is used much more often, according to [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=checkbox%2Ccheck+box%2Ctickbox%2Ctick+box&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccheckbox%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccheck%20box%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctickbox%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctick%20box%3B%2Cc0), and (being a software engineer myself) the term I hear/see the most. As an [HTML input element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkbox#HTML), it's also called a `checkbox`.

[image]